# To get one record for multiple duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a view in which there are multiple duplicates. I want to get only one duplicate. There is no condition for extracting that duplicate .

View :

```
State|ZIP|Sales
AZ    231 asdas
AZ    231 qwerq
FL    12  wqeq
FL    12  lak
KY    1   zxc
KY    1   qwe
```

expected output:

```
State|ZIP|Sales
AZ    231 asdas
FL    12  wqeq
KY    1   zxc
```

There are more than 5000 records. If you do distinct it will still give the same dataset as these are the fields I am trying to extract from the view which is bigger and as you can see the records are not exactly distinct.

Thank You.

Comment: Why do you want `AZ 231 asdas` and not the other? Same for the other rows.  You need to provide the logic for picking those rows.

Comment: Any of the 2 is fine. I just chose to display them as it was the one before that. There is no logic that i why i cant get how to get them. Moreover, those fields are varchar (Cant even put max function). @ollie

Comment: You can use aggregation on a varchar column, did you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation for this since any of the many value is acceptable to you:

```
select state, zip, max(sales) 
from your_table
group by state, zip
```

Comment: It is a varchar field... cant put max

Comment: @Rahul - You can.

Comment: the group by function should have the same fields as in the select clause?

Comment: @Rahul yes. It should. Same number of fields that are without aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

A way  could be based on group by and aggregation function  eg:

```
select state, ZIP, min(Sale)
from my_table 
group by state, ZIP
```

or     max length

```
select state, ZIP, max(length(Sale))
from my_table 
group by state, ZIP
```

Comment: i cant put an aggregation function on a character field @scaisEdge

Comment: You could use max length  and anyway you can use aggregation function on string column

Comment: Shouldnt the group by function have the same number of fields as in the select statement.@scaisEdge

Comment: the answer provide  has the righ number of  column in group by ... you must show in group by all the column that are not  involved in aggregation function ... in this case state, ZIP... anyawy  .. try executing the code  ..